# Flexible Close Command

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am searching for a way how to realize a window close command, which is usable in the window's CommandBindings and by other sources, for example a button. I am working with MVVM. So far, I only found solutions that were either meant for use by CommandBindings or with a simple Command featured inside the MVVM. I need to have one central handler for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.close.aspx

Comment: This is not helpful at all. I also stumbled upon this, but I dont see where this should me at this problem.

Comment: *I need to have one central handler for this.* - Can you elaborate this statement please? I'm not sure what you're looking for. Perhaps you can illustrate some scenarios to clarify your question as well.

Comment: @DHN: I've got a DataSet in my application. At window closing I want to ask for saving the changes made to it. Now I need a central handler asking for this when the window gets closed OR when a certain MenuItem is pressed.

Comment: Why is that not helpful at all? According to your question that shall be what you are looking for. You don't need to write your own static command for closing because its already there. The fact that you dont know where to place it in your code makes me think you should probaby read more about commands and commandbindings.

Comment: Here is a link about CommandBindings and how to place them on Window level. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx

Comment: I know about how to integrate it on window level, the thing is: I need it inside a ViewModel. And this is where I am stumped.

Comment: You will need to use attached properties to solve it. Create an attached property of type Action. Place the property on Window level and bind the action to the action in ViewModel. Once Window is closing execute the action which will invoke the bound method from ViewModel, got it? WPF doesn't allow handling events in ViewModel.

Comment: Ok, I will see what I can do. I will report my approach(es) when I got remarkable changes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use EventToCommand.

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand WindowClosing
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(
                (args) =>{
                    });
        }
    }
```

and in XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding WindowClosing}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```